# How are member variables initialized and constructed?

Tags: c++, member

What happens to member variables when an object is instantiated? Are these the steps?

1. Object is instantiated
2. Memory is allocated for the object
3. The member variable's space is allocated in the RAM.
4. Constructor is called and the member variable is intialized.
5. During constructor execution, member variable's construction is called behind the scenes.

Is this what happens to member variables?

Comment: 5 is correct, although I would say that **before** constructor execution, member variables are  constructed. This is true if you regard 'constructor execution' as meaning executing the code in the body of the constructor.

Comment: The first point sounds like a summary of the whole list to me. 2 and 3 are the same since the memory needed for the object *is* the memory needed for all its members. Although non-trivial members may allocate more memory in their respective constructors.

Comment: The rest is a bit garbled however. However memory is allocated, it is allocated simultaneously for the object and it's member variables. There is one 'allocation' for the entire object.

Comment: Get or have storage. Call constructor. All members constructed in the order they are defined. Enter constructor body. Do any left-over set-up work. Exit constructor body. If an exception is thrown things get messier.

Comment: @cppNoob please don't edit the question to "correct" the list since the comments now no longer make sense as they are referencing the old list.

Comment: Probably best if you separate the construction from the acquisition of storage. A lot of the time you don't have to acquire storage because you already have it.

Comment: Add an answer yourself instead of changing the question. Please revert the question to its former version.

Comment: Hi, sorry for editing the question. So if I've read it correctly, step 2 and 3 are the same, and then before constructor is executed, member variables are constructed (their constructor is called) and then when the constructor of the object is executing, the member variables are initialized?

Comment: @cppNoob No because constructed means the same as initialized

Comment: @cppNoob Member variables are constructed/initialised **before** the body of the containing object is executed.

Comment: @cppNoob Are you familiar with initialisation lists? Are you aware of the difference between initialisation and assignment? These are important concepts in the topic you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's best to explain using an example:

```
class Y
{
public:
    Y(int value) {...}
};

class X
{
public:
    X(int value1, value2): member1(value1), member2(value2) {......}
    Y member1, member2;
};

int main()
{
    auto object = new X(3, 4);
}
```

Execution starts at `main`. `new` allocates space for one instance of `class X`, which includes space for two instances of `class Y`. Then `main` calls the constructor `X::X` with a hidden argument (a pointer to this allocated memory) and two integer arguments. This constructor calls the constructor `Y::Y` twice, for each member. Then the body of `X::X` is executed (it contains `......` in my example).

Each time the `Y::Y` constructor exits, the corresponding member of `class X` is initialized and constructed (formally, its [*lifetime*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) starts).

When the `X::X` constructor exits, the `object` is initialized and constructed (its lifetime starts).

Comment: Hi @anatolyg, if `Y` constructor didn't have a parameter and in the `X` constructor, it didn't use the initializer list, it would still call `Y`'s constructor right?

Comment: Depends on your attitude towards reality. Theoretically, it calls whatever it has to call. But you may be unable to see it, because it may be optimized out. See ["as-if" rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: Hi @anatolyg, one other thing. So the constructor of each data member is called in the constructor? It happens before the constructor's body is executed but after main calls the constructor?